# Upgrading Doctype from XHTML 1.0 Transitional to HTML5 causes layout differences in simple html page

Tags: html, xhtml

I am upgrading doctype for some application and I see the differences in layout. I created small demo to show the problem.
The old `doctype`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

New doctype:

```
<!doctype html>
```

And I see this difference: notice second line is lower
[image]

This is happening when `span` element has `font-size` css attribute. 
What is happening here? How do I debug it? Why layout is different?

Source for the page with old doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>The Transitional</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <h1>
            <div>
               <div>
                  <span>
                     <div><span>Is Your County Obese?</span></div>
                     <div><span style="font-size: 12px;">Select your county to see how it compares with other counties in the country</span></div>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </h1>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Source for the page with new layout:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>The HTML5</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <h1>
            <div>
               <div>
                  <span>
                     <div><span>Is Your County Obese?</span></div>
                     <div><span style="font-size: 12px;">Select your county to see how it compares with other counties in the country</span></div>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </h1>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Source of the side-by-side view:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>The HTML5</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div style="display: flex" >
    <iframe src="doctype1.html" style="width: 30%; height: 300px;" ></iframe>
    <iframe src="doctype2.html" style="width: 30%; height: 300px;" ></iframe>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because your code is broken beyond belief. How did that ever work in XHTML? You're putting everything INSIDE the `<H1>` -that means the the default styling for H1 still applies, even though you reduce the font-size to 12 px. Stop breaking semantics, and create a proper structure.

Comment: oh my! You are correct. Thank you!

Comment: Your page is not XHTML. It may have a XHTML doctype, but that doesn't make it XHTML! It is not well-formed XML and wouldn't even display at all if it would have had an extension of `.xhtml`

Comment: So the actual reason for the changes in display is that with the new doctype, the browser now displays things in standards mode rather than quirks mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a properly structured version:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>The HTML5</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="top">
         <h1>Is Your County Obese?</h1>
         <p>Select your county to see how it compares with other counties in the country</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```